# How to control the total row count of a stream table in DolphinDB?

Tags: streaming, persistence, dolphindb

I need to insert records to a persistent stream table, but I'm concerned about it growing too large.

I aim to cap the row count at specific rows (e.g. 1000). This would not only reduce memory usage for stream tables, but also prevent excessive disk space consumption due to table persistence.

The following configurations seem ineffective in controlling the total row count:

```
maxPubQueueDepthPerSite=1200
maxPersistenceQueueDepth=1300
```

Can anyone help me achieve the desired result?

Here's my script *startup.dos* for reference:

```
clearTablePersistence(`h_bb);
h_bbt = streamTable(2000:0,`sj`id`v,[TIMESTAMP,int,bool])

//share h_bbt  as h_bb
enableTableShareAndPersistence(table=h_bbt,tableName=`h_bb,preCache=10,cacheSize=60,retentionMinutes=60)
if(existsDatabase("dfs://xq")){
  db=database("dfs://xq")
  h_bbp = loadTable(db, `h_bbp )
  subscribeTable(tableName="h_bb", actionName="h_bb", offset=-1, handler=append!{h_bbp}, msgAsTable=true ,batchSize=100,throttle=1,persistOffset=true)
}
else{
  db=database("dfs://xq", VALUE,  2022.01.01..2040.12.31)
  h_bbt1 = table(2000:0,`sj`id`v,[TIMESTAMP,int,bool])
  h_bbp = db.createPartitionedTable(h_bbt1, `h_bbp , `sj)
  subscribeTable(tableName="h_bb", actionName="h_bb", offset=-1, handler=append!{h_bbp}, msgAsTable=true ,batchSize=100,throttle=1,persistOffset=true)
}
```

Because the persistent data is very large, it takes a long time to load during each startup. I have to call the `clearTablePersistence` function to remove this data first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure three parameters within the `enableTableShareAndPersistence` function: ***cacheSize***, ***retentionMinutes***, and ***preCache***.

***cacheSize***: Set the maximum number of rows of  the stream table to keep in memory. If it is 0 or unspecified (default -1), all rows are kept in memory. If you use a positive integer smaller than 100,000, it's automatically set to 100,000.

***retentionMinutes***: Define how long (in minutes) a log file will be kept after last update. Expired log files are automatically deleted. The default value is 1440 (i.e., one day).

***preCache***: Specify the number of recordsto be loaded into memory from the persisted stream table on disk. If it is not specified, all records are loaded into memory, which would result in a long loading times during startup. To solve this, set a smaller value.